# Dynamic sql to get count from all tables by date in oracle

Tags: dynamic-sql

I am trying to get count from all the tables in particular schema for particular date. I know how to get counts but struggling with Adding where clause. Please advice.

Comment: what database you're working with? For Oracle Database, please refer to dba_objects view which contains the CREATED column, LAST_DDL_TIME column.

Answer (score 0):

in you plsql code:

```
select count(*) from dba_objects where object_type=''TABLE'' and owner=v_schema_name and created > v_date; 
-- v_schema_name and v_date are passed in variables
```